# Where has my File Explorer contents gone

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I updated to Windows 10 many weeks ago, all has worked fine.

I used my PC yesterday, albeit via RDP.

Today, I'm on my PC, and when I navigate to File Explorer, all I see are Quick access, Libraries and Homegroup

I installed innosetup today, but this is the only change to my system.

[image]

Other than attempting a system restore do I have any other options (such as, did I accidentally change a setting some where).

Please note, the search doesn't appear to ever end either, meaning the screen shot I've shown remains exactly the same 20 minutes after.

Comment: Try "sfc.exe/scannow" from command prompt

Comment: First diagnostic step: Open a command prompt and try `dir c:\ ` ; after that, try dir `c:\users` , etc... i.e. try browsing the disk from the command prompt.  Second step: Try installing Explorer++ (it's donateware) and see what it tells you is on your disk. Third step: Create another account and see what Explorer does from there - most settings that can cause this behavior are per-user. obtw, you can browse the disk from a web browser too - just put e.g. `c:\ ` in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the issue was simple as it could be....

Restart the PC.

After the reboot, it's working as expected.